# Highcharts- how to get focus only when the cursor enter the point?

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart with a series that contains few points

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'line',
    height: 300
},

series: [{
    data: [{x:3, y:3}, {x:10, y:10}, {x:20, y:20}]

}]
```

});
});

see example http://jsfiddle.net/yoav_barnea/Cg2dn/3/

As you can see form the example, when moving the cursor between points, every point get the focus (the marker hover state and tooltip) **before** the cursor reached to it...(somewhere in the middle-of-the-road )

I want to change that behavior and get the focus **only** when the cursor enter the marker.
(so when the cursor is between points, no point will get the hover state, nor tooltip will be shown)

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use scatter series, and set `lineWidth: 1`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Cg2dn/4/

Comment: thanks,  type:"scatter" did the trick (lineWidth does have any impact on the behavior)

Comment: @Pawel Fus If I could give you ten upvotes, I would. Highcharts is very hard googling sometimes. :)